# Variable for WiX bin directory path?

Tags: path, wix, bin

Is there an environment variable pointing to the WiX bin directory path? I want to use torch in the post-build event of my project, but I cannot find this variable. I cannot hard-code the path because the wixproj is shared by group.

Variables like $(WixTargetsPath) and $(WixTasksPath) are for MSBuild. These are not what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/02/23/WiX-3-Tutorial-Generating-filedirectory-fragments-with-Heat.exe.aspx), $(WIX) is the install path.

Comment: I tried all the complicated variables, but not this simplest one. It works, thanks!